# How to migrate SharePoint files to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sharepoint, google-cloud-storage, etl

We have tones of files in SharePoint now we need to move these files to Google Cloud Storage to build a centralized Data Lake, one of the options is to build a Cloud Dataflow application to read files via SharePoint Rest API and put them into GCS, what are other options (applications and/or protocols)

Comment: I think there are some options for onPrem SharePoints... is it onPrem SharePoint in your solution? Are you plan to do it once for migration or create some permanent pipeline/replication solution?